# "Failed to load JSON sprite sheet in PixiJS: Error with JSON.parse unexpected character - How to resolve?"

Tags: javascript, json, pixi.js

```
Failed to create player animated sprite: Error: [Loader.load] Failed to load http://localhost:3004/sprites/playerSpritesheet.json.
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
    node_modules pixi/assets/lib/loader/Loader.mjs/load/promises<@http://localhost:3004/static/js/bundle.js:76516
```

I get the above error before the following statement is exected:

**createPlayerAnimatedSprite().then(player => {**

I looked up the latest Pixi.js documentation here: https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Spritesheet.html, but it doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with my JSON.

Could it even possibly be an issue with my development server not reading JSON? Just throwing things out there. What could be going wrong here?

**Game.jsx:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import { AnimatedSprite, Assets, Spritesheet } from 'pixi.js';
import InputHandler from '../utils/InputHandler';
import { CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, PLAYER_SIZE, PLAYER_SPEED, GRAVITY, JUMP_HEIGHT, JUMP_SPEED } from '../utils/GameConstants';
import { platforms } from '../utils/Platforms'; // Corrected the import path here
import { createPlayerSprite, createPlatformSprites } from '../utils/CreateSprites';
const { PLAYER_COLOR_DEFAULT, PLAYER_COLOR_LEFT, PLAYER_COLOR_RIGHT, PLAYER_COLOR_JUMP, PLAYER_COLOR_DESCENT, PLAYER_COLOR_FALL_LEFT, PLAYER_COLOR_FALL_RIGHT } = require('../utils/PlayerAnimations');

// Define the collision detection class
const Bump = require('../utils/Bump');

// Define the paths to the sprite sheet JSON and the image file
const playerSpriteSheetPath = '../sprites/playerSpritesheet.json';
const playerSpriteSheetImage = '../assets/images/playerSpritesheet.png'; // Adjust this path based on your project

// Define the animation sequences using frame names from the sprite sheet
const animationSequences = {
  idle: ['idle_frame'],
  walkLeft: ['walk_left_1', 'walk_left_2'],
  walkRight: ['walk_right_1', 'walk_right_2'],
  jumpRight: ['jump_right'],
  jumpLeft: ['jump_left'],
  fallRight: ['fall_right'],
  fallLeft: ['fall_left'],
  shootRight: ['shoot_right'],
  shootLeft: ['shoot_left']
};

// Utility function to create an animated sprite from the sprite sheet
async function createPlayerAnimatedSprite() {
  // Load the sprite sheet JSON data using PIXI.Assets.load
  const spriteSheetData = await Assets.load(playerSpriteSheetPath);
  
  // Load the sprite sheet image using PIXI.Assets.load
  const spriteSheetImage = await Assets.load(playerSpriteSheetImage);
  
  // Instantiate a Spritesheet using the loaded image and JSON data
  const spriteSheet = new Spritesheet(spriteSheetImage, spriteSheetData);
  await spriteSheet.parse(); // Parse the sprite sheet to extract textures
  
  // Create an animated sprite with the idle frames
  const frames = animationSequences.idle.map(frameName => spriteSheet.textures[frameName]);
  const animatedSprite = new AnimatedSprite(frames);
  animatedSprite.animationSpeed = 0.1; // Set the animation speed
  animatedSprite.play(); // Start playing the animation
  return animatedSprite;
}

// Utility function to create a bullet sprite
function createBullet(PIXI, bulletWidth, bulletHeight) {
  const bullet = new PIXI.Graphics();
  bullet.beginFill(0x000000); // Bullet color (black)
  bullet.drawRect(0, 0, bulletWidth, bulletHeight); // Use bulletSize for width and height
  bullet.endFill();
  bullet.distanceTraveled = 0; // Add distanceTraveled property to the bullet and set to 0
  return bullet;
}

const Game = () => {
  const gameContainer = useRef(null);

  // Define dy in the outer scope
  let dy = 0;

  // Add a variable to store the player's last facing direction
  let lastFacingDirection = 'right';

  // Define the game area dimensions
  const GAME_WIDTH = CANVAS_WIDTH * 5;
  const GAME_HEIGHT = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

  const MAX_BULLET_DISTANCE = 1000; // Define the maximum distance a bullet can travel

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create PixiJS application and append to the game container
    const app = new PIXI.Application({
      width: CANVAS_WIDTH,
      height: CANVAS_HEIGHT,
      backgroundColor: 0xffffff,
    });
    gameContainer.current.appendChild(app.view);

    // Create a container to hold all game objects
    const gameScene = new PIXI.Container();
    app.stage.addChild(gameScene);

    // Create platform sprites using the createPlatformSprites function and assign them to the variable platformSprites
    const platformSprites = createPlatformSprites(PIXI, platforms);
    platformSprites.forEach(sprite => gameScene.addChild(sprite));

    // Initialize input handler
    const inputHandler = new InputHandler();

    // Create an instance of Bump
    const b = new Bump(PIXI);

    let bullets = []; // Array to store active bullet sprites
    const BULLET_SPEED = 5; // Speed of bullets



    // Create player animated sprite using the createPlayerAnimatedSprite function
    createPlayerAnimatedSprite().then(player => {
        console.log('Player sprite created:', player); // Add this log statement

        // Set initial position of the player object (modify as needed)
        player.x = CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
        player.y = CANVAS_HEIGHT - PLAYER_SIZE;

        gameScene.addChild(player);
        console.log(player.x, player.y);


        // Inside the gameLoop function
        const gameLoop = (delta) => {
          console.log('Game loop running'); // Add this log statement

          const { x, y } = player;
          let newX = x;
          let newY = y + dy;
          let newDy = dy + GRAVITY;

          // Handle shooting based on input (e.g., spacebar)
          if (inputHandler.isKeyJustPressed('x')) {
            const bulletSize = 10; // Specify the desired bullet size
            const bullet = createBullet(PIXI, 20, 10);
            // Set the bullet's initial X and Y position to the center of the player
            bullet.x = player.x + player.width / 2 - bullet.width / 2;
            bullet.y = player.y + player.height / 2 - bullet.height / 2;
            // Use the last facing direction to determine bullet velocity
            bullet.vx = lastFacingDirection === 'right' ? BULLET_SPEED : -BULLET_SPEED;
            bullets.push(bullet);
            gameScene.addChild(bullet); // Add the bullet to the gameScene container
          }

          // Update bullet positions and check for collisions
          bullets.forEach((bullet, index) => {
            // Update bullet position
            bullet.x += bullet.vx;

            // Increment the distanceTraveled property of the bullet
            bullet.distanceTraveled += Math.abs(bullet.vx);

            // Check for collisions with platforms or other objects
            for (const platformSprite of platformSprites) {
              if (b.hit(bullet, platformSprite)) {
                // Remove bullet from the stage and the bullets array
                gameScene.removeChild(bullet); // Remove the bullet from the gameScene container
                bullets.splice(index, 1);
                break;
              }
            }

            // Optionally, check for bullet expiration (e.g., distance traveled)
            // and remove expired bullets
            if (bullet.distanceTraveled >= MAX_BULLET_DISTANCE) {
              // Remove bullet from the stage and the bullets array
              gameScene.removeChild(bullet); // Remove the bullet from the gameScene container
              bullets.splice(index, 1);
              return; // Skip the remaining checks for this bullet
            }

          });

          // Check collisions after applying horizontal and vertical movement
          let isOnGround = newY + PLAYER_SIZE >= CANVAS_HEIGHT;

          for (const platformSprite of platformSprites) {
            // Use the hit function from the Bump library to check for collisions
            if (b.hit(player, platformSprite)) {
              // Use rectangleCollision for collision response
              const collision = b.rectangleCollision(player, platformSprite, true);
              if (collision === "bottom" && newDy >= 0) {
                // Player is above the platform
                isOnGround = true;
                dy = 0; // Reset vertical velocity
              }
            }
          }

          // Reset player color to default
          player.tint = PLAYER_COLOR_DEFAULT;

          // Handle horizontal movement based on input
          // Handle horizontal movement based on input
          if (inputHandler.isKeyPressed('ArrowLeft')) {
            newX -= PLAYER_SPEED;
            lastFacingDirection = 'left'; // Update last facing direction
            if (!isOnGround) { // Check if the player is in the air
              player.tint = dy > 0 ? PLAYER_COLOR_FALL_LEFT : PLAYER_COLOR_FALL_LEFT; // Orange if descending, blue if ascending
            } else {
              player.tint = PLAYER_COLOR_LEFT; // Change color to left movement color
            }
          } else if (inputHandler.isKeyPressed('ArrowRight')) {
            newX += PLAYER_SPEED;
            lastFacingDirection = 'right'; // Update last facing direction
            if (!isOnGround) { // Check if the player is in the air
              player.tint = dy > 0 ? PLAYER_COLOR_FALL_RIGHT : PLAYER_COLOR_FALL_RIGHT; // Teal if descending, blue if ascending
            } else {
              player.tint = PLAYER_COLOR_RIGHT; // Change color to right movement color
            }
          } else if (!isOnGround && dy < 0) {
            player.tint = PLAYER_COLOR_JUMP; // Set to jump color if player is jumping straight up
          } else if (!isOnGround && dy > 0) {
            player.tint = PLAYER_COLOR_DESCENT; // Set to descent color if player is falling straight down
          } else if (isOnGround) {
            // Set to default color if player is on the ground and not moving horizontally
            // Use the last facing direction to determine the default color
            if (lastFacingDirection === 'left') {
              player.tint = PLAYER_COLOR_LEFT;
            } else if (lastFacingDirection === 'right') {
              player.tint = PLAYER_COLOR_RIGHT;
            } else {
              player.tint = PLAYER_COLOR_DEFAULT;
            }
          }

          // If the player collides with a platform or the bottom of the game area, prevent further falling
          if (isOnGround) {
            dy = 0; // Reset vertical velocity
          }

          // Handle jump based on input
          if (isOnGround && inputHandler.isKeyJustPressed('z')) {
            dy = -JUMP_HEIGHT;
            // The jump color is already set in the horizontal movement handling section, so no need to set it here
          } else if (dy < 0) {
            // Modify the vertical velocity using JUMP_SPEED
            dy += GRAVITY * JUMP_SPEED;
          } else {
            // Apply gravity during descent or when not jumping
            dy += GRAVITY;
          }

          // Apply gravity during descent or when not jumping
          dy += GRAVITY;

          // Use dy to calculate newY value
          newY = Math.min(player.y + dy, CANVAS_HEIGHT - PLAYER_SIZE);

          // Update player's position
          player.x = newX;
          player.y = newY;

          // Update the game scene position to keep the player centered on the screen
          gameScene.x = -player.x + CANVAS_WIDTH / 2;
          gameScene.y = -player.y + CANVAS_HEIGHT / 2;

          // Constrain the game scene position to keep it within the game area
          gameScene.x = Math.min(Math.max(gameScene.x, -(GAME_WIDTH - CANVAS_WIDTH)), 0);
          gameScene.y = Math.min(Math.max(gameScene.y, -(GAME_HEIGHT - CANVAS_HEIGHT)), 0);

        }; // End game loop logic

        // Start the game loop
        console.log('Starting game loop'); // Add this log statement
        app.ticker.add(gameLoop);

    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Failed to create player animated sprite:', error);
    });



    // Clean up the PIXI application when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      app.destroy(true);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div ref={gameContainer} />;
};

export default Game;
```

**playerSpritesheet.json:**

```
{
  "frames": {
    "idle_frame": {
      "frame": {"x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "walk_left_1": {
      "frame": {"x": 64, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "walk_left_2": {
      "frame": {"x": 128, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "walk_right_1": {
      "frame": {"x": 192, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "walk_right_2": {
      "frame": {"x": 256, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "jump_right": {
      "frame": {"x": 320, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "jump_left": {
      "frame": {"x": 384, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "fall_right": {
      "frame": {"x": 448, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "fall_left": {
      "frame": {"x": 512, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "shoot_right": {
      "frame": {"x": 576, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    },
    "shoot_left": {
      "frame": {"x": 640, "y": 0, "w": 64, "h": 64},
      "sourceSize": {"w": 64, "h": 64}
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    "image": "../assets/images/playerSpritesheet.png",
    "size": {"w": 704, "h": 64},
    "scale": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you type `http://localhost:3004/sprites/playerSpritesheet.json` into a browsers url, what do you get?

Comment: Check devtools network tab for the request to playerSpritesheet.json

Comment: @Keith I just get the main game screen. It doesn't show me the contents of the .json file in the browser.

Comment: @James I get status 304

Comment: I put both the json and image in the /public directory and that seemed to resolve the issue. The paths I used previously were correct, however. So I'm not sure that solves this question.